# .DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-studio

Develop android system application environment through android studio.

1. copy *out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/framework_intermediates/classes.jar* to *app/libs*. rename framework.jar
2. add
   `provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`
   to *build.gradle*
3. add `options.compilerArgs << '-Xbootclasspath/p:app\\libs\\framework.jar'`

when rebuild project ,occuring a error

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.systemapplication"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multidexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:3.0.2'
}

Error:(6, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method multidexEnabled() for arguments [true] on 
DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main,
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle file.

Comment: I have posted  gradle file.

Comment: I think you need this `multiDexEnabled true`. See the doc https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.

Comment: yes. I am based on the documentation. still occur a error.

Answer (score 0):

This error `app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` generally occures due to adding external library which may not be compatible with your `compileSdkVerison`.

Enable Multidex in your project. To enable it open `build.gradle(Module:app)` file and then in `defaultConfig` block write **multidexEnabled true**.

Now, Clean & Rebuild your project.

Comment: `android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        multidexEnabled true`  Error:(6, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method multidexEnabled() for arguments [true] on DefaultConfig_Decorated{name=main,